# Парк "Царицыно"

Tags: склонение

Возник спор с оппонентом о правильности написания названия парка (не района) "Царицыно". Оппонент доказывает, что написание "в Царицыне" правильное. Но это не название города или деревни, это конкретное название парка. Ответьте, как правильно писать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Название парка — тоже топоним (географическое название). И он — славянского происхождения.

> Топонимы славянского происхождения, оканчивающиеся на -ово, -ево, -ино, -ыно, не склоняются в сочетании с родовым словом: из района Люблино, в сторону района Строгино, к району Митино, в городе Иваново, из деревни Простоквашино, до края Косово. Если же родового слова нет, то **возможны оба варианта, склоняемый и несклоняемый**: в Люблине и в Люблино, в сторону Строгина и в сторону Строгино, в Иванове и в Иваново, из Простоквашина и из Простоквашино, до Косова и до Косово, к Митину и к Митино, 8-й микрорайон Митина и 8-й микрорайон Митино. При этом склоняемый вариант соответствует строгой литературной норме. Словарь Л. К. Граудиной, В. А. Ицковича, Л. П. Катлинской «Грамматическая правильность русской речи» указывает: «В образцовом литературном стиле (со сцены, с телеэкрана, в радиоречи) эти формы следует склонять».
>
> http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/73-rubric-90